# Permission Error occur While i save the python file

Tags: openerp-7

How to change the user permission in openerp. i have access denied.  while i  save the python   file 
 I cannot  save  the python file .

i got an error messages like this :-

```
Error opening file '/opt/openerp/openerp-7.0-20140803-231125/openerp/addons/account/account.py': Permission denied
```

The file on disk may now be truncated.!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the permission on specific file just go to the path where your file is located from the terminal

You should do some think like this

**/opt/openerp/openerp-7.0-20140803-231125/openerp/addons/account$ sudo chmod 755 account.py**

then you should easily Edit and Save your account.py python File.

Comment: Thank you  i add sudo chown and set the permission  its working .but how to set chgrp its not working.